# Deleted duplicate Question with valuable content

Tags: discussion, support

I've just learned that we can't vote to undelete if a mod deleted a Question:

> [**How do I rename the wp-admin folder with the admin_url filter?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43560/12615)
>
> [image]

It's marked as duplicate of [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106/12615).

But, although incomplete, I'm seeing a unique <sup>`1`</sup> value on the technique that the OP (of the deleted Q) is trying to work with. Hence this request to "vote to undelete".

<sup>`1` I'm researching the matter and there are bits not present elsewhere.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have undeleted the question now. Not sure if you can flag the question for mod attention. If that’s not possible, ask in chat.

Comment: The red card obfuscated the possibility of the flag option :)

Comment: Sometimes, these links are inactive: visible, but you cannot click it. I’d need a 10k sock puppet to see that. :)

Comment: It still redirects to Q#106 if I'm not logged in... Can you repro?

Comment: Yes. Probably because of the close reason.

Comment: Oh, the logic for this is sound indeed. Case closed, thx!